# Convert a COLORREF to a const char

Tags: c++, mfc

How do I convert the value from a COLORREF to a const char. Currently I try to use the variable as it is, but I get the following error from my compiler.

Error   106 error C2664: 'HC_Set_Color' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'COLORREF' to 'const char *'  c:\b_gdm_src_wtx\gdm_pda\src\gdmsmallsampledlg3d.cpp    2289

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered that the compiler complains because COLORREF is simply not a const char and you can't treat it like one?

Comment: How do you want to represent it as a string?

Comment: `COLORREF` is a typedef of `DWORD` which is a typedef of `unsigned long` most often. It doesn't make much sense to represent this as a `const char*` even if you used the correct cast.

Answer (score 2):

You can take one and return a string representation like this:

```
void COLORREF2string(COLORREF cr, char* buffer) {
    itoa(GetRValue(cr), buffer, 10);

    buffer += strlen(buffer);
    *buffer = ' ';
    itoa(GetBValue(cr), buffer + 1, 10);

    buffer += strlen(buffer);
    *buffer = ' ';
    itoa(GetGValue(cr), buffer + 1, 10);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
COLORREF c = RGB(34, 54, 12);

char buf[16]; // 16 is big enough to hold any possible RGB combination
              // with spaces between the numbers

COLORREF2string(c, buf);

cout << buf << endl;
```

Which will print

```
34 54 12
```

You can make it a fancier representation like `R: x B: x G: x` yourself if you want, but remember to adjust the size of your buffer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the spec you're trying to follow: set_color.html#g406b806a5ed60dd9950fb12b0ce2077c">http://www.openhsf.org/docs_hsf/Hoops3DGS/hc_ref_manual/group_**set**_color.html#g406b806a5ed60dd9950fb12b0ce2077c

You need a string of the form "(r=0.5 g=1 b=0)".  Here's one way to get it:

```
COLORREF color = RGB(128,255,0);
stringstream ss;
ss << "(r=" << GetRValue(color)/255.0 << " g=" << GetGValue(color)/255.0 << " b=" << GetBValue(color)/255.0) << ")";
HC_Set_Color(ss.str());
```